# How to insert values of treeview into database c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, treeview

I have simple problem.I have treeview like this

[image]

In this picture parent node is my course and child nodes are abilities of this courses.Course and abilities can be define custom in my app.

This is my database structure:

[image]

Dore in English is Course And Maharat in English is abilities and StudentId Is for test.

This tree view fetch data from database and every node has specific id.I want to insert checked values into TblStudentMahrat in one click.but i do not know how to do this.

Please Help me.tnx

Comment: Use a table valued parameter to insert multiple values into the database with a single insert statement.

Comment: So where *exactly* are you stuck? Do you know how to get the data from the control? Do you know how to connect to your datasource? Do you know how to insert data? Post your best try then.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Anyone can not help me??